# How to return correct quantity of DB rows if I will not show some rows using external check

Tags: php, acl, symfony

I use symfony 3 and symfony-acl component for creating REST API service. Here is my code that gets a list of articles from DB:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Article');
$articles = $repository->findByParams($paramFetcher);
```

$paramFetcher object has parameters from the request: limit, sorting, filters etc. If limit is equals 100, then there will be 100 elements in $articles array. And I want to deny access to some articles using symfony ACLs. So, after I get $articles from DB, I delete some elements, that user has not 'VIEW' access to:

```
foreach ($articles as $k=>$article) {
    if (!$this->isGranted('VIEW', $article)) {
        unset($articles[$k]);
    }
}
```

Then there wil be less than 100 elements in $articles array. How to return correct quantity of articles? Or how do popular services solve this problem in their API? Google, for instance. Maybe I should disable limit parameter? Or I should do queries to the DB recursively?

Comment: Maybe you should refactor you code to keep for example roles in article table that are allowed to view.